# Trigger Method in Sibling Component Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

need your assistance once again. Here's my situation. VueJS2 (vue-cli project) no Vuex.
I have `parent` component, `child1` and `child2`.
`child1` is a form that gets data from `child2`(which is a table). Upon clicking on table row's checkbox in `child2`, we fill up the form in `child1` this is done by `event` emitting via `parent`(picture 2). 
`child1` has a button and `reset method`(see picture 1) to clear its fields. My task is: when I 'uncheck' checkbox in table row `child2`, form in `child1` has to be cleared. How do I do this, specifically, how do I access `reset method` in `child1` from `child2` and use that method from `child2` basically.
I know how to pass data from child to child, but cant get my head around how to be able just manipulate child's data from its sibling.
Please help! Thank you in advance!

[image: Snippet of reset method in child1]
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? A code example would help also. Are you trying to pass a data from child to another child? Or maybe you want to emit an event from one child and listen to it in another child..

Comment: Just emit another event when the checkbox is unchecked and have that be responsive to the other child component.

Comment: @samayo have no access to code at the moment. Well, I know how to pass data child - child, but what i need is to use the method `reset` that already exists in `child1`(pic), looking for a way to trigger it from `child2` without passing any data, just to be able to clear fields in `child1` from `child2`.
right now, that `reset` method does clearing fields but only when i press button `clear` which is a part of `child1`. Sorry if its too confusing

Comment: @Ohgodwhy `have that be responsive to the other child component.` who do I do that. I have confused myself, it mustn't be that difficult

Comment: in another words, how can I clear `child1`'s form fields from `child2` by unchecking checkbox, or pressing button in `child2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have 2 child components, and you want to tell child1 to execute a method (reset) from your child2 compoent without passing any props.

Well, in that cases your option is limited to using an event Bus.

Check this example. When you click on a button from `CompB` it executes a methods inside another child component: `CompA`

```js
var Bus = new Vue()

var compA = {
  data: () => ({ name: 'Primary' }), 
  
  template: `<p> Comp A is: {{name}}</p>`,
  
  methods: {
    reset () {
      this.name = 'RESETED'
    }
  },
  
  created () {
   let self = this;
    Bus.$on('resetA', function (payload) {
      self.reset()
    })
  }
}

var compB = {
  template: `<p> Comp B <button @click="resetCompA"> Clear A </button> </p>`,
  methods: {
    resetCompA () {
      Bus.$emit('resetA')
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
   'comp-a'  : compA, 
   'comp-b' : compB
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <comp-a></comp-a>
  <comp-b></comp-b>
</div>
```

Comment: cant thank you enough! does what i need it to do! Cheers!